# jquery.ajax multiple data retrieval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I use this code, I only manage to retrieve recaptcha_response_field. If I remove recaptcha_response_field, I retrieve recaptcha_challenge_field. However, I am unable to retrieve the two at the same time. 
I only managed to send 1 data.

```
challengeField = $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
responseField = $("#recaptcha_response_field").val();

var html = $.ajax(
    {
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: "recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField + "&recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField,
        url: "../ajax.recaptcha.php"
    }).responseText;

if(html == "success")
{
    $("#captchaStatus").html("Success. Submitting form.");
    return true;
}
else
{
    $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
    Recaptcha.reload();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you wrote this line `data: "recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField + "&recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField,` was wrong.

you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
 }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });
```

or 
          `data: {recaptcha_response_field : responseField , recaptcha_challenge_field :challengeField`

thanks,
Chintu

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
data: {
    recaptcha_response_field: responseField,
    recaptcha_challenge_field: challengeField
}
```

??

What do you mean that `$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]` and `$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]` are not both set "inside" `ajax.recaptcha.php`.

That's impossible Firebug's Net-Tab shows that the request just works fine.

Did you check your server logs (enable post data logging temporarily )

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I mean. I don't know why however...

I'm using joomla if that can helps.

There's nothing relevant in the servers logs.

Thank you

Comment: just btw. can't you just use some of the existing recaptcha / joomla plugins? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/reCaptcha or just google for it

Answer (score 1):

Maby something like this?

```
var challengeField  = $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val(); 
var responseField   = $("#recaptcha_response_field").val();

/* Debug */ alert ("Going to send channengeField with value '" + challengeField + "', and responseField with '" + resonseField + "'");

$.post ("../ajax.recaptcha.php", { 
        recaptcha_response_field:   responseField, 
        recaptcha_challenge_field:  challengeField 
    },
    function(data) 
    {
        /* Debug */ alert ("Data Recieved: " + data);

        if (data == "success")
        {
            $("#captchaStatus").html("Success. Submitting form.");

            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again"); 
            Recaptcha.reload(); 

            return false; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  data: "recaptcha_response_field=" + $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val() + "&recaptcha_challenge_field=" + ("#recaptcha_response_field").val(),
```